# Shortcut for deleting previous branch in git

Tags: command-line, git

In git it would be helpful to be able to easily delete the previous branch I was on. You can't delete the branch you're on so you need to check out a new/existing branch and delete the previous you where on by writing it's full name.

```
git checkout new_branch
git branch -D old_branch_with_really_long_and_hard_name
```

What I really want is to be able to do this:

```
git checkout new_branch
git branch -D -
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`-` doesn't work, but `-` is just an alias for `@{-1}` and that *does* work. So you workflow would be this:

```
git checkout new_branch
git branch -D @{-1}
```

*Amendment:*

Turning this into the git alias `git done`:

```
git config --global alias.done '!f() { git checkout master && git branch -D @{-1}; }; f'
```

Comment: I realise that `@{-1}` doesn't really roll of the keyboard either, but is's shorter than full branch names in most cases.

Comment: Was just writing a git alias of the same name, thanks!

Comment: I suggest done = "!f() { git checkout - && git branch -D @{-1}; }; f" instead. Since your base branch might be something different than master (or main).

Comment: On Windows I had to switch the single quotes to double quotes to get the alias config line to work.